# What is the most idiomatic way to redirect to a child creation page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Suppose a `Parent` model with a one-to-many relationship to several `Child` models. From a details page for a `Parent`, I want to link to a `Child` creation form. A `Child` entity created there is then supposed to belong to the `Parent`.

I understand how to "work the context" in order to connect the `Child` with the `Parent`. My question is about getting a `Parent` reference from the `Parent` view to the `Child` creation view.

I have found some solutions that seem very "low level" (e.g. setting the parent ID in `TempData`). I assume there is a more idiomatic (maybe even type-safe) way to do this.

I am using razor templates in Areas, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I am assuming that this has been answered before and I'm just using the wrong search terms here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data-structure let's say `CreateChildViewModel`

```
public class CreateChildViewModel
{
     public int ParentId {get;set;}
     //... rest of the props
}
```

Now you can navigate to your CreateParentChild action and pass the id in the link using tag helpers `<a asp-controller="YourController" asp-action="CreateParentChild" asp-route-parentId="YourParentId"></a>`

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateParentChild(int parentId) =>
    View(new CreateChildViewModel { ParentId = parentId });
```

and then in your view you can store this id in a hidden input field

```
@model YourNamespace.CreateChildViewModel
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ParentId" />
```

once you post this back to create the child you will have the Id in the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateParentChild(CreateChildViewModel vm) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

I'd say as a rule of thumb try to never use `TempData`